# How to traverse table in Jquery and add a class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a simple table of two rows.  The first column is required, but the others are not; **however, I would like them to be required in pairs**.  So if the user enters a value for Quantity3, then Size3 should also now be required.

As a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NaRts/7/

```
<tr>
    <td><input name="qty1[492]" class="qty required" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="qty2[492]" class="qty" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="qty3[492]" class="qty" type="text"></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input name="size1[492]" type="text" class="size required" ></td>
    <td><input name="size2[492]" type="text" class="size" ></td>
    <td><input name="size3[492]" type="text" class="size" ></td>
</tr>
```

And the simple jQuery I have is:

```
$('.qty').keyup(function() {
    var s       = $(this).attr('name');            // = qty3[418]
    var qtyID   = s.replace(/[^1-9\[\]]/g, "");    // = 3[418] 
    var SizeID  = "size" + qtyID;

    var $sizeInput = $(this).closest('tr').next().find(SizeID);
    $sizeInput.css('background-color', 'green');
    $sizeInput.addClass('required'); 

   //I tried this too but it didn't work 
   //$(this).parent().find(SizeID).addClass('required');                


});​
```

​
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Removed .each

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.qty').keypress(function(){
      var s       = $(this).attr('name');
      var qtyID   = s.replace(/[^1-9\[\]]/g, "");  
      var sizeID  = "size" + qtyID;
      var sizeInput = $("input[name='" + sizeID + "']");    
      $(sizeInput).css('background-color', 'green');
      $(sizeInput).addClass('required');
    });  
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked, but why are you doing .each, if I may ask?  Shouldn't this work for `$('.qty').keypress`?  Regardless, thank you again!

Comment: you're right it'll work without the .each. I've edited the solution.